# Automate Regex in OS X

Tags: regex, macos, markdown, automator

I frequently use TextWrangler to run RegEx copy-replace operations on files, and I'd like to automate this, using Automator in OS X. For instance, in the following scenario I take a TEXT output from Pinboard.in and then run a few regex search/replace operations in TextEdit before saving as a file.

1. Start with http://feeds.pinboard.in/text/t:tag/
2. Run the following search replace in TextWranger (to convert to Markdown links in outline form):

   - Find: `^\[(.*)\]\r(.*)\r`
   - Replace with: `* [\2](\1)\r`
3. and then strip away all lines which aren't prefaced with `*`

   - Find: `^[^\*].*\r`
   - Replace: [leave blank]

My goal would be to have this all saved as a script that could be run on the pinboard URL and saved as a file. Any ideas? Thanks!